# Return "true" if all td.has_pais_dist has text otherwise return "false"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to check whether `td.has_pais_dist` has text (meaning value) or not. I'm doing in this wau:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var activateBtnNext = $("#distribuidorBody").find(".has_pais_dist").filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()).length > 0;
  }).length > 0;

  var boolVar = $('#distribuidorBody .has_pais_dist:empty').length > 0;

  console.log(activateBtnNext);
  console.log(boolVar);
});
```

In a set of HTML element like this:

```
  <table id="contenedorDistribuidores">
    <thead>
      <tr class="tableHead">
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>País</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="distribuidorBody">
      <tr>
        <td>kksddfkdfkdf</td>
        <td id="distTd-1" class="has_pais_dist"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>dfgdfgdfg</td>
        <td id="distTd-2" class="has_pais_dist"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>fsdfkjdsf</td>
        <td id="distTd-3" class="has_pais_dist">Some text</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

But both returns "true" and that's wrong since the first two TD hasn't text value. What I'm doing wrong? You can take a look [here](http://jsbin.com/juqaq/1/edit?html,js,console).

Comment: you are measuring 2 different things

Comment: @charlietfl I tried to do the same in two ways I forgot to mention that

Comment: the point is the 2 tests shown aren't trying to attain the same goals. Not 100% clear what your overall objective really is either. All have no text or any one has no text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have true if there are no empty elements so

```
var boolVar = $('#distribuidorBody .has_pais_dist:empty').length == 0;
```

or

```
var boolVar = $('#distribuidorBody .has_pais_dist').is(':empty')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you need as a result. I'm guessing you need the filtered items that do have text. If this is correct just remove `.length > 0` from your filter function.

```
  var activateBtnNext = $("#distribuidorBody").find(".has_pais_dist").filter(function () {
      return $.trim($(this).text()).length > 0;
  });//.length > 0; this is setting your var to a bool, instead of keeping the filtered elements

  console.log(activateBtnNext); // this is an array with the las element that does have text
  console.log(activateBtnNext.length); // this is the number of elements that have text, in this case 1
  console.log(activateBtnNext[0]); // this is the element that does have text
```